# trying to split comm world to multiple comm worlds or blocks in MPI?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

What i am trying to do basically is to divide a group of 8 processors to 4 sub groups and hence 4 sub communicators so that processors in each communicator will have id 0 and 1. Here is the output i get

> rank = 0 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 2 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 6 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 4 newrank = -32766
>
> rank = 7 newrank = 1
>
> rank = 5 newrank = -32766
>
> rank = 3 newrank = 1
>
> rank = 1 newrank = 1

The expected output is

> rank = 0 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 2 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 6 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 4 newrank = 0
>
> rank = 7 newrank = 1
>
> rank = 5 newrank = 1
>
> rank = 3 newrank = 1
>
> rank = 1 newrank = 1

As you can see it is getting to the expected result but i am unable to determine what is causing the negative value. It seems printing uninitialized variable or the data wasn't set there. Any help is appreciated?

```
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int NPROCS = 8; //trying on 8 processors

    main(int argc, char *argv[])  {


    int rank, new_rank, numtasks;

    MPI_Group  orig_group, new_group;
    MPI_Comm   new_comm;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

    /* Extract the original group handle */
    MPI_Comm_group(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &orig_group);


    int i;

//need two iterations to split the blocks into 8 sub blocks...
//first iteration ranks assignment   0 1 2 3   0 1 2 3
//second iteration ranks assignment  0 1  0 1  0 1  0 1 
    for(i=0; i<2; i++){  


        /* Divide tasks into two distinct groups based upon rank */
        if (rank < NPROCS/2) {

            int j;

            int ranks[8] = {0};

                //list of ranks for that sub group
                for(j=0;j<NPROCS/2;j++){
                ranks[j] = j;
            }



            MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks, &new_group);

        }
        else {

            int j;

            int ranks[8] = {0};

                //list of ranks for that sub group
            for(j=NPROCS/2;j<NPROCS;j++){
                ranks[j-NPROCS/2] = j;
            }


            MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2, ranks, &new_group);
        }


        /* Create new new communicator and then perform collective communications */
        MPI_Comm_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, new_group, &new_comm);


        MPI_Group_rank (new_group, &new_rank);

        //here i assign the new_group identifier to orig_group so that in next iteration
        //MPI_Group_incl(orig_group, NPROCS/2 ... can use the new_group as orig_group
        orig_group = new_group;
        NPROCS = NPROCS / 2;   // divides NPROCS to half
        rank = new_rank;

    }


    printf("rank= %d newrank= %d \n",rank,new_rank);

    MPI_Finalize();


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the second iteration, processes with initial ranks 0 and 1 fall into the first branch of `if` (which is ok), *all other* processes go into the `else` branch (which is not).

So, processes with initial ranks 0 and 1 get their group successfully; processes with initial ranks 2, 3, 6, 7 have group ranks 2 and 3 and also get their group at the second iteration; but processes with initial ranks 4 and 5 have at the second iteration group ranks 0 and 1 and are not included into any group. Hence the negative ranks.

Your code would probably work if you use `new_rank` instead of `rank` inside the loop (assigning `new_rank = rank;` before the loop).

Although I would advise more straightforward creating of groups: calculate bounds and then create groups (unless you really need an hierarchical group structure).